# how can i do python nested list to csv (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, list, nested

I have a nested list. How can I print it as csv with Python Pandas. I've looked at similar issues. I couldn't find the solution I was looking for.
Thanks for your answers.

[image: python nested list to csv]

Comment: Please don't post images. Post sample (small) input and expected output as text.

Comment: I think you could use pandas.read_json if there is a json file or you can use pandas.DataFrame.from_dict(dict) in case of a dict.

Comment: @Andrej Keseli
I couldn't add the codes because they were too long. I'm sorry for that.

Comment: @arp.arthur
Thank you so much. I solved it because of you

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use pandas.read_json if there is a json file or you can use pandas.DataFrame.from_dict(dict) in case of a dict.

json file:

```
import pandas as pd

df_json = pd.read_json('json_file.json')
```

dict:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'name': 'John', sports: {'first': 'boxing', 'second': 'surf'}}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
```